# Prove the nxn matrix is positive

Tags: linear-algebra

Im trying to solve this exercise:

Let $n$ be a positive integer and A the $nxn$ matrix

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 1/2 & 1/3 &\dots & 1/n \\
    1/2     & 1/3 & 1/4 & \dots & 1/(n+1) \\
    \vdots \\
    1/n      & 1/(n+1) & 1/(n+2) & \dots & 1/(2n-1)
\end{bmatrix}$

Prove that A is positive.

Already notice that $A$ is symmetric.

If $X=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\neq 0$ im trying to prove $X^TAX>0$.

$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1&x_2&\dots&x_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 1/2 & 1/3 &\dots & 1/n \\
    1/2     & 1/3 & 1/4 & \dots & 1/(n+1) \\
    \vdots \\
    1/n      & 1/(n+1) & 1/(n+2) & \dots & 1/(2n-1)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{bmatrix}=$

$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1&x_2&\dots&x_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1+ x_2/2 + x_3/3 +\dots + x_n/n \\
    x_1/2+x_2/3 + x_3/4 + \dots + x_n/(n+1) \\
    \vdots \\
    x_1/n      + x_2/(n+1) + x_3/(n+2) + \dots + x_n/(2n-1)
\end{bmatrix}=$

$x_1^2+\frac{x_1x_2}{2}+\frac{x_1x_3}{3}+\dots+\frac{x_1x_n}{n}+\frac{x_2^2}{3}+\frac{x_2x_3}{4}+\dots+\frac{x_2x_n}{n+1}+\dots+\frac{x_nx_1}{n}+\dots+\frac{x_n^2}{2n-1}$

Its clear to me that the sum has positive adds ($x_i^2$), but also have negative adds... my problem is how conclude this sum is positive.

Comment: I think you should try using determinant.

Comment: Possible duplicate as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2996169/514490).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix

Comment: Thank !!! Actually is a duplicate, so sorry. Thanks again!!