# Proving that the $n \times n$ Hilbert matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, hankel-matrices, hilbert-matrices

> Prove that the following matrix is positive definite. $$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac12 & \dots & \frac1n \\ \frac12 & \frac13 & \dots & \frac1{n+1} \\ \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \frac1n & \frac1{n+1} & \dots & \frac1{2n-1} \end{bmatrix} $$

---

I tried to do a couple of thing without succes (it's immediate that $A=A^t$):

**First:** I tried to show this by definition: In this case, the matrix is real so, let $v^t=(x_1,...,x_n)^t$ be a real vector, I tried to show that $v^tAv>0$. I then arrive to
$$x_1^2+x_1x_2+\frac{2x_1x_3}{3}+\dots+\frac{x_2x_n}{n+1}+\frac{x_n^2}{2n-1}$$ but I don't know how to show that this last equation is $>0$, is there some identity to show this?

**Second**, I tried to define the matrix as a inner product, that is $a_{ij} = \langle v_j, v_i \rangle$ where $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a ortonormal base for $\mathbb{R}^n$. How can I define those $v_j$'s?

**Third**, I tried to show that the minors of the matrix are all positives, I tried to do it by induction over the matrix size, for $n=1$ is trivial because $A$ is $1>0$ in this case, for $n=2$, we have

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 1/3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and then

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 1/3 \\
\end{vmatrix}=1/3-1/4>0$$

If we suposse that for size $n-1$ we have determinant positive then I tried to calculate $\det(A)$ using determinants of size $n-1$ all positives. (I did it expanding by the first column):

$$\det(A)=1\det\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & \dots & 1/n+1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1/n+1 & \dots & 1/2n-1 \\
\end{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}\det\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & \dots & 1/n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1/n+1 & \dots & 1/2n-1 \\
\end{bmatrix}+\dots+(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}\det\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & \dots & 1/n \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1/n & \dots & 1/2n-2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then, how can I do to show $\det(A) > 0$ keeping in mind that every determinant is positive?

Comment: Second attempt is a good way. That's the [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix), and it's a [Gramian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix).

Comment: The preceding is probably the easiest way, but if you are curious, [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975779) gives the explicit Cholesky factorization $A=LL^T$ with
$$L_{ij}=\frac{\sqrt{2j-1}\Large{\binom{i}{j}}}{i\Large{\binom{i+j-1}{j}}}$$
With $P=L^{-T}$, this gives a change of basis for the quadratic form associated with $A$, such that $P^TAP=I$, i.e. in the new basis the quadratic form is $\sum_i x_i^2$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2996169/prove-the-matrix-is-positive?rq=1